# How do I set expiration settings to Envelope Definition?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to set expiration settings to my Envelope Definition, but I'm unable to.
I am using the following as a reference to create and send my envelope: 

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs

I have already tried the following:

```
envDef.ExpireAfter = "1";
envDef.ExpireEnabled = "true";
envDef.ExpireDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm ff");
```

The document does send with every other setting that I've set, however, there are no expiration settings set to it despite the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Inbar states, you'll need to create an Expirations object and apply it to your envelope definition. As per [DocuSign's Dev blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-reminders-expirations/), you can do so like this:

```
var expirations = new Expirations("1", "true", "0"); //ExpireAfter, Enabled, Warning days
var reminders = new Reminders("0", "true", "0");  //ReminderDelay, Enabled, Frequency
//results in no reminders and no expiration warning sent, envelope expires one day after sending
```

and then apply that to the `envelopeDefinition.Notification` parameter

```
envelopeDefinition.Notification = new Notification(expirations, reminders, "false"); //Expirations, Reminders, UseDefaults
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the Expiration class in the C# model in the client.
that object would have 3 fields (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/1d125f362ba8ae33edc2a72a713fc1e6e8b55314/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Model/Expirations.cs) 
ExpireAfter - string that is a number of days to expire after envelope changed status to "sent"
ExpireWarn - string that is a number of days before envelope is expired that you would warn user (via email) that envelope is about to expire.
ExpireEnabled - "true" - to allow you to customize this envelope (vs. using the account's defaults)

I believe if ExpireAfter == ExpireWarn than the email won't be sent.
I think you can set ExpireAfter to 1 and ExpireWarn to 0 which should result in an email right away, I haven't tested it yet. Otherwise - need to wait a day to test this....